# Which table contains settings for countries available for shipping

Tags: admin, database, backend, sql

I'm trying to figure out, which database table is storing settings for enabled countries for shipping.
I have to disable some countries with sql install script

Answer (score 3):

## Put it in database

You are talking about `System > Config > Sales > Shipping Methods > <whatever method> > Ship to Specified Countries`?

Everything under `System > Config` is saved in `core_config_data`.

Don't write with sql to this table, because you have to be in the right scope (default, website, store)!

Instead you can just use `Mage::getConfig()->saveConfig()`.

```
public function saveConfig($path, $value, $scope = 'default', $scopeId = 0)
{
    $resource = $this->getResourceModel();
    $resource->saveConfig(rtrim($path, '/'), $value, $scope, $scopeId);

    return $this;
}
```

**BE CAREFUL**
When you `saveConfig()`, then neither cache is updated nor config-xml-object.

I use this method to update config:

```
/**
 * sets config value in database, cache and simple xml object
 *
 * @param $path
 * @param $value
 */
protected function _setConfigValue($path, $value)
{
    Mage::app()->getConfig()->saveConfig($path, $value);
    $code = $this->_getStore()->getCode();
    $this->_getStore()->setConfig($path, $value);
    Mage::app()->getConfig()->setNode("stores/$code/" . $path, $value);
    Mage::app()->getConfig()->saveCache();
}
```

As I said above, be careful with the scope!

The path for `system->config->general->countries` is: `general/country/allow`

## Put it config.xml

You can just put it in local.xml or config.xml in:

```
<config>
     <default>
        <general>
            <country>
                <allow>DE,US,LE</allow>
            </country>
        </general>
     </default>
</config>
```

Comment: Im talking about system->config->general->countries options and locale options

Comment: added the path and a second option.

Comment: `$conf = new Mage_Core_Model_Config();

$conf ->saveConfig('general/country/allow', "US", 'default', 0);`

Comment: Don't do this... `new Mage_Core_Model_Config()` use `Mage::getConfig()` instead!